# How do i get the response out of the spider?

Tags: python, scrapy

so the jist is i have a spider into which i want to pass an ID which gets strapped onto the end of the url i want to scrape. I'm having difficulty getting the result out though. So the question is "How do i get the response out of the spider?"

example code

```py
import scrapy


class WarTimelineSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "WarTimelineSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["URL HERE"]

    def __init__(self, id=None, **kwargs):
        super(WarTimelineSpider, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.start_urls = (f"BASEURL/id={id}")

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(self.start_urls, self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        name_selector = "SELECTOR HERE"
        for timeline in response.css():
            yield {
                "stats": timeline.css(name_selector).extract_first()
            }


timeline_class = WarTimelineSpider(war_id)
```

I attempted

```py
print(timeline_class)
```

but that is giving me

```
<WarTimelineSpider 'WarTimelineSpider' at 0x1fc5fe21d08>
```

as an output